# Setting random number generator seed to a "random" number

Tags: random, pid, kdb, random-seed

Could you, please, let me know how I could set the random number generator seed in KDB to a more or less "random" number?

I am trying to do the following:

```
\S .z.i
```

But somehow it does not work. \S seems to expect an explicit integer, not a variable.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just like with any `\x` command, when you need to pass a non-literal as an argument you should use [`system`](http://code.kx.com/q/ref/syscmds/#system):

```
system"S ",string .z.i / no backslash before S!
```